# 16.10 software updater not installing updates

Tags: updates, 16.10

i recently had 16.10 installed. it was checking for updates and installing them. now it doesn't though i have it all set to "display immediately". i can start the software updater myself, and it appears to download them and make a list, but then it just gives a window that says my computer is up to date. this seems a bit unlikely since it's been a month since anything seemed to be installed. it just skips the window showing the list and asking if i want to install. is there something i need to change to get it to install the updates? thank you. todd

Comment: Did you have network access while installing Ubuntu? Normally this checks to install updates while installing Ubuntu itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the frequency from

```
system settings --> software & updates --> updates,
```

[image]

You could also run `sudo apt updates && sudo apt dist-upgrades` from the terminal to see if you have any *if you don't trust the updater*.

Now there are two ways to do updates:

1. From terminal with:

   - `sudo apt update`

     ```
     The above command will update the package list to see if any changes 
     have occurred requiring you to update
     ```
   - If updates are present then you can run:

     ```
     sudo apt dist-upgrade
     ```
2. Software updater:

   ```
    Which does the same thing as in opion 1 but using a 
    GUI (graphical user interface)
   ```

That you haven't updated in a month doesn't automatically mean its not working when you whenever you try to and it doesn't. Now if there is an issue with your network then when you run update from the terminal or updater it should notify you.

You can also check if your repositories are enabled so you can receive update from the `system settings --> software & updates --> other softwares` section. And enable any that you need and isn't.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Today for some reason a number of updates did install. This information is very useful for me.